# MySQL 5.7: Scope of SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL for SELECT

Tags: mysql, optimization, transaction, isolation-level

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) states that without the GLOBAL or SESSION keyword, the isolation level will be valid for the next transaction and will be reverted to the session default after the transaction was commited.

With autocommit enabled, what is the scope of an transaction isolation level for a SELECT statement?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
```

Is a SELECT statement a complete transaction, meaning the isolation level will be reverted to session default after the SELECT was executed, or does a SELECT somehow not represent its own transaction, meaning that the isolation level will not be restored after a SELECT statement?

Comment: My understanding, in MS SQL at least, is that every statement (including SELECT) is a transaction. Whether you specify a TRANSACTION block or not just tells SQL whether to encapsulate multiple statements into one and *when* to commit. To which your ISOLATION LEVEL would apply to that block. Maybe someone has additional insight.

Comment: Let's see the entire transaction; it is hard to discuss a single `SELECT` by itself, without knowing how the resultset will be used.

Comment: @RickJames what if the select is the only query that is run?

Comment: The question for me is, is a SELECT a selfcontained transaction if autocommit is enabled without a BEGIN statement, or do subsequent queries, be it SELECT or UPDATE, count as part of the same transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To answer question in comment)

There are three ways to build a transaction:

(1)

```
BEGIN;
any number of statements  -- all in one transaction
COMMIT;
```

(2)

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON;
...
statement  -- This is a transaction
...
statement  -- This is a different transaction
```

(3)

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = OFF;
...
statement
statement
COMMIT;  -- 2 statements in a transaction

statement
statement
COMMIT;  -- another 2 statements in a different transaction
```

Comment: Okay so based on this answer it would mean that with autocommit enabled, the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL would be reverted to the session default after the SELECT statement has been executed, hence I am marking this as the correct reply. Thanks!